# Networking issues with strange setup

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, static-ip

I'm having the hardest time getting web access to a server. I have a machine running Linux Mint(host) and another running a Ubuntu server(client). My host machine has internet access from a DHCP server as follows:

```
ifconfig wlan0
>>wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr (Removed for privacy)  
      inet addr:192.168.1.146  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::5627:1eff:fe0b:8a11/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1222773 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:671280 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1722602133 (1.7 GB)  TX bytes:69823730 (69.8 MB)
```

I'd like my client machine to have internet access through the host eth0 port with a static IP. Any help is appreciated. This has been a headache.

*PREVIOUS ATTEMPTS*:

---

Setting a static IP for the host computer on my default gateway. Then, on the client computer, running:

```
sudo echo "auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.146
broadcast 192.168.1.255
netmask 255.255.255.10
gateway 192.168.1.1" >> /ect/network/interfaces
```

---

Setting a wired connection to "Share to other computers" on the host computer and running this on the client:

```
sudo ifup eth0
```

This seems to run forever and never resolves.

---

Setting up a bridge connection doesn't work. `wlan0` to `eth0` isn't supported. Same reason the gateway didn't work.

Comment: Remove the `#` from your commands.  That's the **nix character for "Don't pay attention to anything after this on this line".

Comment: I wasn't entering it in my commands. I know it would be seen as a comment otherwise. I'm just signifying that I'm using the root user. I'll remove it and add sudo to clairify.

Comment: You need to configure /etc/network/interfaces as static.  See my answer to come...

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure `/etc/network/interfaces`:

There should be, in that file, the following lines in this order:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.146
    netmask 255.255.255.10
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

That way `eth0` will gain a static IP instead of the default DHCP address.

Comment: I did exactly this on the client computer. Right now, I'm configuring the host to run as a gateway with a VLAN. I'm using [this tutorial](http://thesystemmaster.com/unix/gateway_mint.php) as a guide at the moment. Will it work if I use `wlan0` and `eth0` instead of `eth0` and `eth1`?

Comment: Ahh, I see that I forget to include `iface eth0 inet static` in my example above. I'll change that.